# Animation inside 'if' statement does not work

Tags: ios, animation, if-statement

This is my issue:

I have a few animation blocks and they are all getting executed fine. But I also want to perform some animations, only if a specific `BOOL` value is true.

The `BOOL` is properly taking the `TRUE` value and the code enters the `if` statement because my log comments are getting printed. Only the animation does not seem to appear. I have tried with different `CGPoint` values and still the same.
Perhaps there is something I am missing out about the animations.

I have not been using them a lot.
Any help would be great!

Here is a code sample:

```
// line 4 - second particle
UIImageView* particle8 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"particle"]];
particle8.frame = CGRectMake(p8.x, p8.y, particleWidth, particleWidth);
[self addSubview:particle8];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     particle8.frame = CGRectMake(p7.x, p7.y, particleWidth, particleWidth); }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[particle8 removeFromSuperview]; }];


if (_isSmartGridOn) {
    // line 2b - first particle
    UIImageView* particle9 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"particle"]];
    particle9.frame = CGRectMake(ep.x - 5, ep.y - 5, particleWidth, particleWidth);
    [self addSubview:particle9];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         particle9.frame = CGRectMake(p10.x, p10.y, particleWidth, particleWidth); }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){[particle9 removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

Comment: Try adding UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState to your animation options.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo or a copy/paste error:

```
particle8.frame = CGRectMake(p10.x, p10.y, particleWidth, particleWidth);
        ^ should be 9         ^^     ^^ looks like these might be wrong too
```

Comment: Hi, you're right about the typo but it does not solve the problem. I have copied, pasted and re-written this many times in different ways to find a solution, many typos occur but even when fixed, the animation does not appear. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Then I'd suggest using a breakpoint, stepping through each line of that if, and making sure that the values of each variable are what you expect them to be.